# Android Studio not opening correctly

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio and it was working fine. I then closed it and when I tried to reopen I only get the "Tip of the Day" showing but nothing else. I ran the "studio.bat" and here is the output:

```
2020-09-17 14:38:57,660 [   1746]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk]
2020-09-17 14:39:00,584 [   4670]   WARN - ugins.textmate.TextMateService - Missing builtin bundles, checked:
C:/Users/micro/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
2020-09-17 14:39:01,489 [   5575]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider
2020-09-17 14:39:14,499 [  18585]  ERROR - openapi.wm.impl.WindowInfoImpl - Frame bounds are invalid: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=-2286,width=2561,height=1466]
java.lang.Throwable: Frame bounds are invalid: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=-2286,width=2561,height=1466]
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:145)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameInfoHelperKt.updateFrameInfo(FrameInfoHelper.kt:94)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameInfoHelperKt.access$updateFrameInfo(FrameInfoHelper.kt:1)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameInfoHelper.updateAndGetModificationCount(FrameInfoHelper.kt:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameInfoHelper.updateAndGetModificationCount(FrameInfoHelper.kt:50)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ProjectFrameBounds.getModificationCount(ProjectFrameBounds.kt:37)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentWithModificationTrackerInfo.getCurrentModificationCount(ComponentInfo.kt:80)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.commitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:186)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.commitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:89)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl$commitComponentsOnEdt$$inlined$withEdtContext$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl$1.invokeSuspend(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:655)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.EdtPoolDispatcherManager.processQueue(EdtPoolDispatcher.kt:54)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.EdtPoolDispatcherManager.access$processQueue(EdtPoolDispatcher.kt:18)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.EdtPoolDispatcherManager$scheduleFlush$1.invoke(EdtPoolDispatcher.kt:32)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.EdtPoolDispatcherManager$scheduleFlush$1.invoke(EdtPoolDispatcher.kt:18)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.EdtPoolDispatcherKt$sam$java_lang_Runnable$0.run(EdtPoolDispatcher.kt)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:309)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2020-09-17 14:39:14,503 [  18589]  ERROR - openapi.wm.impl.WindowInfoImpl - Android Studio 4.0.1  Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
2020-09-17 14:39:14,511 [  18597]  ERROR - openapi.wm.impl.WindowInfoImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2020-09-17 14:39:14,511 [  18597]  ERROR - openapi.wm.impl.WindowInfoImpl - OS: Windows 10
2020-09-17 14:39:14,519 [  18605]  ERROR - openapi.wm.impl.WindowInfoImpl - Last Action:
```

- I don't think it's a PATH issue because it was working fine before.
- I tried starting it as an administrator, no luck.
- It uses 40% of CPU in the task manager even though the window is not showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `y=-2286` seems to cause that error. Maybe there was an error while writing the last known window size and position.

Comment: do you have an idea how I can reset it without reinstalling everything?

Comment: Ah, solved it! I was able to select the window in the task bar but it still did not show up. But when I hovered over the preview from the task bar, I can right click in the preview windows and select maximize. That brings the window back! Thank you :)